# Minimalist VoIP smartphone application

Tags: open-source, mobile, voip, whatsapp, progressive-web-application

I am looking for a minimalist VoIP smartphone application which is similar to *WhatsApp*, *Line*, *Viber*, *Tango*, *Kik* and alike, can run at least on *Android* and has the following features:

### Necessary features

- Isn't owned by *Facebook, inc.*
- Is gratis to use
- Allows textual chatting by default
- Allows disabling the option for textual chatting (which I would personally replace with email correspondence)
- Gives the option to allow or disallow voice calling (if chatting isn't off)
- Allows deleting the *account* of the app from the app itself (unlike Telegram which requires deletion after X months from app deletion or from website)

### Non necessary features

- [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software)
- Gives the option to allow or disallow voice `and` video calling
- Prints a warning (or has the option to print a warning) each time before a video button was `possibly-mistakenly` clicked to turn on video in a voice call
- Allows usage without a phone number (based on email and/or account → if someone wants tat)
- Isn't necessarily aimed only for smartphones and could also work on a PC

### My question

What would be an example of a VoIP smartphone application which is fair by my standard?

Comment: Just posted. Maybe someone who is familiar with [Jami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jami_(software)) (formerly Ring) can write an answer on that if it fits the other requirements. I've never used that myself, so I can't really do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Threema](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.threema.app)** would fit your requirements almost completely:

- **Isn't owned by Facebook, inc.:** Nope. It's owned by Swiss-based [Threema](https://threema.ch/) and has a strong focus on privacy. So it's just the opposite to those "kraken"
- **Is gratis to use:** Using it is gratis, yes. There's just a very reasonable one-time fee for the license (less than 3 bucks). Per device that is (you can transfer the license to a new device – but you can't use a single license on multiple devices at the same time). You've just missed the 50% XMas special ;)
- **Allows textual chatting:** it does.
- **Gives the option to allow or disallow voice-only calling:** you can do so in the settings of the app (a toggle-switch).
- **run at least on Android:** Android and iOS are supported
- **FOSS:** partly. The Android/iOS clients are not, "Threema Web" is.
- **Allow usage without a phone number:** you initially create a "Threema ID", no personal data needed to supply. Optionally, you can give your phone number and/or email address – which is used to find contacts from your address book who also use Threema and sync them. No data stored on their servers (they promise to just "compare hashes")
- **could also work on a PC:** you can do that using "Threema Web" – either via their server, or by hosting your own (Threema Web is FOSS)

I'm using Threema myself, it works pretty reliable. Long distant calls have clear voice (usually better than landline) – I've used that accross continents even. Being a happy Threema user, I can recommend it warmly. Only wish it were fully FOSS and available via F-Droid… ;)

Comment: Hello dear Izzy ; for yours I value your help in this community ; I have updated the question a little bit - I hope you have some spare time to review the changes I have done which I humbly find not essential so there is no serious contradiction between the updated question and the answer ------ I believe that updating the answer accordingly, adding some more text will help us both helping others seeking a more minimal, more moral and more free VoIP experience (especially the SEO will become stronger after such changes). In great plea, please do,